Old oil and gas exploration "units" appearing in assay report
I'm reading old gas exploration reports and depths appear to be quoted as "176.7 metres, 38 units" in assays of gas composition (image below of example) and I was wondering if anybody new what this referred to? This has been really bugging me. Since I'm here I'll also ask what for the "h" means as in "1600h.". Sorry for the perhaps silly question - trying to log data for a (personal) project.
The image was taken from page 363 of this report.

Thanks!

Could you link the report?  I've posted a guess in the answers but more context would give more certainty about the "units".

@f.thorpe https://www.mrt.tas.gov.au/mrtdoc/tasxplor/download/97_4088/97-4088.pdf page 363 is the example I gave (though about 100 pages have these assays on them)

Thanks, I've added the link to your question.

38 units: These are "hotwire units" as indicated in Appendix 1A of the report (pages 38 and 39 of the pdf report).  This is not my area of expertise, but "hotwire units" in this context could represent readings from a hot wire anemometer used to measure gas concentration or flow rate during the drilling process.
18/07/97, 1600h: This is the date and time when the measurement was taken. In this case, it indicates July 18th, 1997, at 4:00 PM (1600h is military time or 24-hr clock).

The time thing definitely checks out! I don't think thats what the 'units' means though (thanks for taking the time to answer) simply because directly below this line is a table of the assays of various gases.

I've edited my answer to better explain "units".  Thanks for the linking the PDF, that helped.

Thanks for the answer, makes sense, pity they didn't provide more context
